# Add custom filed in lerandash question page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

We want to add custom field in question page in learndash using Wordpress how to do this please help me

Answer (score 1):

1. Navigate to LEARNDASH LMS > QUIZZES
2. Click on the quiz you’d like to edit
3. Click on the Settings tab
4. Scroll down to the Administrative and Data Handling Settings section
5. Turn on the setting next to Custom Fields

https://www.screencast.com/t/gVPUOoCtHEPw